# Laravel Tests: Example Test Failed

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Laravel y con las pruebas unitarias es algo con lo que no me había involucrado y decidí comencé a hacerlo hoy, estoy  trabajando con la version 7.5.2 de Laravel y me enteré que para la versión 7 hay un nuevo comando que nos facilita la ejecución de las pruebas que es : `$ php artisan test`

Por lo que lo ejecuté y recibí este error:

```html
$ php artisan test
Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

   RUNS  [2mTests\Unit\[22mExampleTest
  • [2mbasic test[22m

  Tests:  [2m2 pending[22m

   PASS  [2mTests\Unit\[22mExampleTest
  ✓ [2mbasic test[22m

   RUNS  [2mTests\Feature\[22mExampleTest
  • [2mbasic test[22m

  Tests:  1 passed, [2m1 pending[22m
[22m

   FAIL  [2mTests\Feature\[22mExampleTest
  ✕ [2mbasic test[22m

  Tests:  1 failed, 1 passed

  Expected status code 200 but received 500. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.

  at D:\isendWell\isendwell\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\Constraint.php:116
    112|         if (!empty($description)) {
    113|             $failureDescription = $description . "\n" . $failureDescription;
    114|         }
    115|
  > 116|         throw new ExpectationFailedException(
    117|             $failureDescription,
    118|             $comparisonFailure
    119|         );
    120|     }

  1   D:\isendWell\isendwell\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\IsIdentical.php:93
      PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint::fail("Expected status code 200 but received 500.")

  2   D:\isendWell\isendwell\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Assert.php:2887
      PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\IsIdentical::evaluate("Expected status code 200 but received 500."
)
```

Investigué un poco sobre el error ya que la ruta "/" abre sin ningun inconveniente, de todas maneras aquí dejo el código:

```html
Route::get(
    '/',
    function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
);
```

El archivo se encuentra en la ruta especificada y como les comento la ruta me abre sin ningún inconveniente, estuve revisando otros posts en **Stackoverflow** y en **Laracast** y la verdad no consigo nada que me ayude a identificador el problema.

Codigo del Test:

```html
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    #use RefreshDatabase;
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

`use RefreshDatabase;` Lo tengo comentando porque me ejecuta el driver sqlite a pesar de que uso postgresql y tengo algunas function triggers en las migraciones que dan error con sqlite. Cabe destacar que la clase RefreshDatabase no forma parte del código del test por default, lo agregué solo porque en otro foro leí que de esta forma el test pasaba la prueba, pero en mi caso no funcionó.

Comment: deberias de mostrar el `test` para ver si todo esta bien.

Comment: Listo, ya lo estoy mostrando.

Comment: Y si en vez de hacer la prueba a `'/'`, escribes toda tu url `'http://mitura.com/'`